# Limit feeds came from Facebook Graph API i want all feed in single request

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Below is my **code**:

```
$response= $fb->sendRequest('GET', '/me/feed', ['fields' => 'message,type,attachments'], 
            $val->api_token, 'eTag', 'v2.10');
            dd($response);
```

Get only 25 records How to get all feed in single request what should i add them in query string.

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api, “limiting results” But you can not just go and specify the limit as high as you want, different endpoints have different limits on the maximum amount of objects they can return in one request. Once the amount of data you have goes over that, you _have to_ use pagination.

Comment: #04FS i read that document and i already show that pagination array in response but i want to dump  all the feeds in my db.  i did it using pagination but i want it in single call.

Comment: You can “want” all day long, that doesn’t change the fact that it’s not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every commercial API provides `Rate Limiting / Throttling` and `Record Limiting Per Request`. Even Graph API does [Rate Limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting/) and [Record Limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/#datapercall)

When you are requesting let's say 100 records, the 3rd party API server is using it's resources to get you those 100 records. The thing is, there might be many API clients like you who want to use the same API for their usage. So, Rate Limiting helps the API providers to make sure each client is not requesting large set of data together.

Also, it's very unlikely that you will need all data from Graph API at once. It is suggested to use pagination so that you are requesting small number of data per API request.

If you want to save all in your database, You can save in incrementally like get 50 records and store it, then get next 50 and store them and so on..